# What's the motivation for an access token debug step in OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

The following figure is from the paper by Yang et al. (https://paper.bobylive.com/Meeting_Papers/BlackHat/Europe-2016/eu-16-Yang-Signing-Into-Billion-Mobile-Apps-Effortlessly-With-OAuth20-wp.pdf)

[image]

What I wonder is the motivation for step 6 ("AT Debug"). It confuses me because the access token (AT) was just received in the previous step (Step 5), so why send it back to the IdP again right after that?

Comment: I read DEBUG to mean VALIDATE. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens

Comment: Alright, so the motivation is to check if the Token that the 3rd Party Backend (a) receives from the Client (c) in step 5 is indeed a valid token because it could have been tampered with in steps 3, 4 or 5.

Comment: To avoid attacks by token replays, expired tokens, invalid tokens or valid tokens from another IdP.